# Flask conditional rendering

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to create "cards" with details about certain items that fall into a couple of categories, with each card containing items from one category. So for example, the first card will have all items from CategoryOne, the second card will have all items from CategoryTwo. I've added the items to a sqlite database. Each category has a name. Each item has

However, I seem to be getting the same items for each card. That is, the items from CategoryOne show up in both cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it seems you expect to have at least 2 categories returned when you run the query - `categories = session.query(Category).order_by(Category.name)`

But when you start your loop, you do a return after the very first iteration. Before you do this return, you retrieve the items for that specific category. This means the data being sent to your template consists of all the categories **and only the items which belong to just one of the categories.**

One possible way (note that this is just a rough example) of fixing your issue is to creating an array of dictionaries of the form
 `output = [{"category_name": <category_name>, "category_items": <items>}]`

And then you loop through the output in your html file like

```
<div class="col s12 m12 l12">
  {% for k in output %}
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <div>
        <h5 class="card-title">{{k.category_name}}</h5>
                        
      .....
       
        <tbody class="white">
          {% for a in k.category_items %}
            <tr>    
              ...
                  <strong>{{a.name}}</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                  {{a.series}}
                </p>
              ...
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="blue-grey-text text-darken-4 font-medium flow-text">
              {{a.price}}
            </div>
          </td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}  
        </tbody>
      </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Update added on May 11.

Your python code should be something like

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def showList():
    output =[]
    categories = session.query(Category).order_by(Category.name)
    for c in categories:
        if c.name == 'CategoryOne':
            category_id = 1
        elif c.name == 'CategoryTwo':
            category_id = 2
        
        category = session.query(Category).filter_by(id=category_id)
        items = session.query(Item).filter_by(category_id=category_id).all()
        output.append({"category_name": c.name, "category_items": items})
        
     return render_template('index.html',output=output)
```

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comment